# Writing datetime to CSV file in python?

Tags: python, datetime, twitter, tweepy

I want to write datetime object in a csv file. for that i am doing something like like that:

```
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at.encode('utf-8'), tweet.user.name.encode('utf-8')])
```

but i am getting error;
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'encode'

and if i just simply type "tweet.created_at" with out encode

```
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.name.encode('utf-8')])
```

i get this error
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
so how can i write datetime in CSV?

Comment: Well how do you want it to appear? Timestamp? ISO8601 format? Something else? Decide that, turn it into the appropriate number/string, then pass that to the CSV writer.

Comment: yes i want timestamp

Comment: Then have a look in the datetime docs, which tell you how to get it.

Comment: you can use `tweet.created_at.encode("utf-8", "ignore")` , `ignore` removes anything that cannot be encoded.

Comment: @tea-addict that still gives an attribute error. The problem isn't that the string is failing to encode, but that it's *not a string*, and doesn't have that method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right , it is not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strftime` to get your required date time format.

**Ex:**

```
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tweet.user.name.encode('utf-8')])
```